# Sequelize associate not creating foreign key

Tags: mysql, node.js, express, sequelize.js

According to [sequelize documentation](https://sequelize.org/v5/manual/associations.html), Model.hasMany should automatically create foreign key references with constraints. But when i try it in my code it does not. I have to manually add the foreign key to the migration. Please how can i fix this? This is my User model

```
'use strict';

module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
  const User = sequelize.define('User', {
    name: DataTypes.STRING,
    username: DataTypes.STRING,
    email: DataTypes.STRING,
    password: DataTypes.STRING
  });

  User.associate = function(models) {
    // associations can be defined here
    User.hasMany(models.Post);
  };  


  return User;
};
```

and this is my post model

```
'use strict';
module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
  const Post = sequelize.define('Post', {
    title: DataTypes.STRING,
    body: DataTypes.TEXT
  });

  Post.associate = function(models) {
    Post.belongsTo(models.User);
  };

  return Post;
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After much struggle with this I finally figured it out.

The db:migrate command uses the migration files and does not include the model files.

To use the model files instead, I just needed to do this in the app.js file

```
...
...
const db = require('./models');
db.sequelize.init();
```

Although a lot of experience programmers do not recommend this method. They suggest that the best method is manually creating the foreign key in the migration files.

Comment: Hi @Precious Aang, I have the same problem as you has. I tried using this method you have mentioned but i get this error: ` db.sequelize.init is not a function`. can you please help me with this?

Answer (score 0):

To create foreign key, you'll need to put the information of which column is the primary key and the foreign key referred:

```js
'use strict';
module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
  const User = sequelize.define('User', {
    name: { 
       DataTypes.STRING,
       primaryKey: true
    },
    username: DataTypes.STRING,
    email: DataTypes.STRING,
    password: DataTypes.STRING
  });

  User.associate = function(models) {
    // associations can be defined here
    User.hasMany(models.Post, {
        foreignKey: modelId 
    );
  };  


  return User;
};
```

Note that, in your `User`, I defined which column is the primary key and, in `hasMany`, I defined which column on `Post` is the foreignKey.

Comment: I did that. It did not still work. It seems like the migration command uses only the migration files without looking at the models at all.